# Changing the color of the specific day which has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

How can I change the color of the specific day which has been clicked on my calendar?

This is my code:

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
    var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    /**
      * calEvent is the event object, so you can access it's properties
      */
    if(confirm("Would you like to cancel the meal delivery ?")){  
        delete event in backend
        jQuery.post("/vacation/deleteEvent", { "id": calEvent.id } );

        delete in frontend
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); 
    }
},
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the JQuery plugin fullcalendar which I suppose you are using, you can change the color of specific day by his title like this :

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $where = event.title;
    if ($where == 'your title') 
        element.css('background-color', '#bbd2e1');
    else
        element.css('background-color', '#f0c0cb');
            }
```